# How to update using a LIKE operator on JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

I have two tables.  Table Subdivision list of neighborhoods `VARCHAR(100)`  Table `Property_List` has field `legal_desc` which is a `VARCHAR(100)`.

The field `legal_desc` in table `Property_List` has data as follows:

```
Spinner Court L2N235
Federal Way Lp456
Montford appes776d
```

Table Subdivision is the correct values for the neighborhoods as follows:

```
Spinner Court
Federal Way Place
Montford Estates
```

What I need to do is `update Property_List.field_subdivision` based on the look up value in `subdivision.neighborhood`.

I am new to this and am not sure how to construct the MySql query to do this.

Comment: Let's see your query that you are trying

Comment: Update mls_property_list_master_test
set mls_property_list_master_test.subdivision = neighborhood.subdivision
FROM  mls_property_list_master_test, neighborhood
WHERE mls_property_list_master_test.field_LIST_51 LIKE neighborhood.subdivision

Comment: Quick comment.  In your posted sql above, you need to add a `%` to your `where` criteria to take advantage of the `like` statement.  However, this will only match on `Spinner Court` -- the other 2 records don't have a partial match.  What should happen with those?

Comment: If there isn't a match then the field wouldn't get updated.  Only if there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do some poor man's pattern matching but it probably won't be very effective. You'll eventually have to write an algorithm to parse these better.

```
update m
set m.subdivision = n.subdivision
FROM mls_property_list_master_test m
JOIN neighborhood n ON n.subdivision like '%' + m.field_LIST_51 + '%'
```

...or something similar. You may have to take the `LEFT()` of one of the fields to get a match.

Play with this sqlfiddle to see what you need to do: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1418/10